# The volatile "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MyProject' could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

When rebuilding a solution in VS 2017, the "Rebuild All Failed" because I am obtaining multiple

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MyProject' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   MyServices  D:\MySources\MyProject\MyServices\Controllers\MyController.cs

However when I doubleclick on the error and the `.cs` files opens, the red underscore disappear and the error as well.

What could cause such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It can be several different things you are missing.
[See this for some explanation.](https://github.com/Microsoft/msdn-content/blob/master/msdn-lib/Compiler-Error-CS0246.md)

Based on your explanation, my guess is that you are missing a reference between the projects in your solution. (if you have more than 1 project of course)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not wizard, it can be everything, but please check in this file which classes use functions/classes from another project - please try to build only these projects and try to compile current project again. Do you have the same problem?

If it solves your problem, add these projects to build dependencies.